# Using Javascript to play an audioelement (html5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger playing an audio from javascript. I got some html which looks like:

```
<div class='audio' >foo
<audio preload='auto' controls src='test.wav'>
<b>Your browser does not support the audio tag.</b>
</audio>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to trigger it with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.audio').each(function(){
        var audio = $(this).find('audio').get();
        $(this).click(function(){
            audio.volume = 100;
            alert('1 '+audio);
            audio.play();
            alert('2');
        });
    });
});
```

alert('1 '+audio); works as expected and reports audio as HTMLAudioElement. However alert('2'); is not called because I get the error 'audio.play' is not a function. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you mean to say you get an error stating 'audio.play' is not a function? I'm pretty sure it would be correct that 'alert.play' is not a function unless you specifically defined a new alert object with a play method.

Comment: Copy&Paste from Firefox Errorconsole:
Error: audio.play is not a function
 - certainly a good point to ask, but sadly it's true o.O

Comment: That makes more sense - I assumed that's what you meant, but just wanted to be sure there wasn't a typo in your actual code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks perfect. What is the error you are getting is it "alert.play" is not a function or "audio.play" is not a function.

I think

```
var audio = $(this).find('audio').get();
```

returns an array try this

```
var audio = $(this).find('audio').get(0);
```

Comment: Thank you :D - I could hit myself with something heavy right now, but it's a good feeling to have that thing finally running.

Answer (score 4):

Controlling audio without jQuery using just JavaScript is even easier if you give the audio tag an ID:

```
<audio id="myAudioTagID" type="audio/mpeg" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
```

then you can simply get the element and apply .pause(), .start(), stop() :

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudioTagID");
audio.play();
audio.pause();
audio.stop();
```